# Push data from device to device?

Tags: android, communication, p2p

Is it possible to push data directly from one device to another over the **mobile network** without using a server and without wifi or Bluetooth?

(Both have the same app installed.)

How? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Android is capable of **peer to peer communication over 3G**

Google for `android 3G peer to peer` and you will get many hits. And you'll see that you have some hurdles to overcome:

- Identifying own and target Android's internet IP
- Configuring the right sockets etc.
- Getting past firewalls
- And all this is depended on whether or not your telecomm provider allows P2P in the first place.